# NestJS StreamableFile vs responseObject

Tags: node.js, nestjs

Whats the advantage of using Streaming Files (https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/streaming-files) instead of writing the object in the response with NestJS?

```
const data = ...;
response.writeHead(200, {
  "Content-Type": "text/csv",
  "Content-Disposition": `attachment; filename=something.csv`,
});
return response.end(data);
```

vs

```
const data = ...;
const readable = Readable.from([data]);

response.set({
   "Content-Type": "text/csv",
   "Content-Disposition": `attachment; filename=something.csv`,
});

return new StreamableFile(readable);
```

Answer (score 1):

With a `StreamableFile`, you don't need to inject the `@Res()` at all to the route handler, you can set the disposition and content type as a part of an options object as a second parameter to the `StreamableFile` constructor. It also means that if you are unit testing your controller you don't need to mock the `res.writeHead` or `res.end` methods, just assert that the returned instance is essentially equal to a created `StreamableFile` (i.e. has the same props and values).

It's also just one more thing for the framework to take care of that you don't need to worry about. If you prefer writing `res.write` or `stream.pipe(res)` then go for it.